# How to use @ symbol in HTML in a CGI script

Tags: cgi

Sure a very simple question but I can't seem to find the terminology to find the answer in a search!

I'm using a file-uploader CGI script. Inside the CGI script is some code that generates some HTML. In the HTML I need to put an email address using the @ symbol, however this breaks the script. What is the correct way to escape the @ symbol in a CGI script?

The error when using the @ symbol is:
"FileChucker: load_external_prefs(): Error processing your prefs file ('filechucker_prefs.cgi'): Global symbol "@email" requires explicit package name at (eval 16) line 1526."

Many thanks for any help

**Update..**

Hi All, many thanks for the replies - I guess it is perl.. (shows my ignorance of what's going on here perfectly!). The code below shows the problem the @ in 'email@domain.com'.

```
'test$PREF{app_output_template} = qq`

%%%ifelse-onpage_uploader%%%
<div id="fcintro">If you're using a mobile or tablet and have problems uploading, we recommend emailing your CV to: email@domain.com<br><span class"upload_limits">We can accept Adobe PDF, Microsoft Word and all popular image and text file types. (max total upload size: 7MB)</span></div>
%%%else%%%
%%subtitle%%
%%%endelse-onpage_uploader%%%

%%app_output_body%%'
```

Comment: Could you show us the code where you're placing the address?

Comment: Stating which language you're using would be kind of helpful - CGI is not such a thing.

Comment: `\@` will probably work, in the absence of seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `&#64;` instead of `@`.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp

Comment: Thanks mayabelle, its useful to now know 'entity code' is what I should have been searching for!